# iOS - alertView shouldEnableFirstButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I want the user to not be able to click the cancel button on UIAlertView, yet I still want it to be there, but shaded out. I know a `shouldEnableFirstButton` function is there but it doesn't involve cancel button. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: `UIAlertView` does not support the ability to disable the Cancel button.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm doing an application which starts a tutorial when first opened. Part of the tutorial is that you have to fill out something in `UIAlertView`, but since I don't want the user to exit during tutorial, I must shade out the cancel button. Of course I could just open a new UIAlertView if it would be closed, but it wouldn't be that nice. Is there a way to create a custom `UIAlertView`?

Comment: Just create the alert view without a cancel button if the user can't cancel.

Comment: The cancel button will be there in the future though and I want to prepare him for it. The tutorial must look exactly as the real application, however without the ability to cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
UIAlertView *vw = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information" message:@"This is a message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
    [vw show];
```

So, essentially you are setting the "Cancel" as other button.

Now, the following will solve your problem:

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    return NO;
}
```

If you want to perform some action in OK button press you can always do that here:

```
- (void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView
```

Comment: Is there a way that the "Cancel" button would be on the left, not on the right?

Comment: @user2874028 This is a trick we are playing. The alert view knows that the left button would be Cancel, so don't think we can place it in left. Sorry.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for your effort but it doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. However, you can actually create the buttons manually and set them as subview of the UIAlertView. Then based on the title can enable and disable them. Don't know if that will suit you.